# $\int\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ using $sinh(u)=x$

Tags: integration

It is well known that $\int dx*1/(1+x^2) = arctan(x) $ but why when i do the following substitute i get rubbish results?
Let $ sinh(u) = x , cosh(u) * du = dx $ then $\int dx/(1+x^2) = \int \frac{cosh(u)*du}{1+sinh^2(u)} = \int \frac{du}{coshu}$ mathematica gives after resubstuting $ u = arcsinh(x) $ the final function to be $ gd (Sinh^-1(x)) $

Where did this go wrong?

Comment: There is nothing wrong because $gd(x) = \arctan(\sinh(x))$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function#Alternative_definitions.

Comment: i did not know about that!! thanks!!

Comment: I did not know it either. I typed the integral into WolframAlpha, saw that “gd“ is the “Gudermannian function”, looked up that function, and found it :)

Comment: Thank you in either case!

Comment: Use, for example, `$\sin x$` for $\sin x$.